# Is it possible to wait for a child_process in process.on('exit', ...) method

Tags: node.js, process

I'm trying the following

```
process.on('exit', function() {
    child_process.exec('echo hello', /*...*/);
}
```

and want to delay exit until the child process has finished.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, according to doc, [`exit`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit) event is too late to bind any async events. You should instead listen for [`beforeExit`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_beforeexit) event.

> Emitted when the process is about to exit. There is no way to prevent
>   the exiting of the event loop at this point, and once all exit
>   listeners have finished running the process will exit. Therefore you
>   must only perform synchronous operations in this handler.

In `beforeExit` you can do async operation and exit manually:

```
process.on('beforeExit', function() {
  setTimeout(function(){ //run async code
    console.log('beforeExit')
    process.exit(0);  //exit manually
  }, 1000);
});
```